# Overriding association in ActiveModel Serializer - returns all attributes instead of serialized object attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, active-model-serializers

I have 2 models : `Repository` and `Branch`, both of which have a corresponding serializer.

In `RepositorySerializer`, I want to list one default branch. Here's how I'm doing it:

```
attributes :id, :name, :ssh_url, :default_branch
has_many :branches

def default_branch
  object.branches.find_by_name(object.default_branch)
end
```

In `BranchSerializer`, I have:

```
attributes :id, :name
```

`branches` returns all branches properly serialized and only containing `id` and `name` attribute, but `default_branch` returns all the attributes of that branch.

Is there any way to utilize the existing `BranchSerializer` in this case or should I myself return the required attributes from the method `default_branch`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're serializing `default_branch` as an attribute, so the `BranchSerializer` won't kick in.
Add

```
  has_one :default_branch do
    object.branches.find_by_name(object.default_branch)
  end
```